# Reflection.Assembly::Load method

Tags: c#, reflection

When I try to load an assembly using this method, what's the differences between long name and partial name?
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7zy9z5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), I get this:
for long name: A full assembly reference is required if you reference any assembly that is part of the common language runtime or any assembly located in the global assembly cache.
for partial name: the runtime looks for the assembly only in the application directory

And a customer encountered an error because I used partial name to load the assembly, but the assembly was exactly in the application directory.

So, I want to know, are there any other differences between long name and partial name when using the Load(string) method?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What error was encountered by the customer?

Comment: It definitely says that `LoadWithPartialName` looks both in the application directory and the GAC. If it is found in the GAC, that version will be used over the one in the application directory. Also, `LoadWithPartialName` has been obsolete since .NET 2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

phoog -- The exception is failed to load the assembly: Could not load file or assembly  or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

mike z -- Yes, I know this method, but I just want to know the difference between long name and partial name when using the Load(string) method

Comment: BTW, what's the exact meaning of 'the application directory' in MSDN? If my application in folder A, and another assembly(named assm1) in GAC calls the code 'Assembly::Load' to load assembly assm2, the application calls assm1. So, in my scenario, what is the "APPLICATION DIRECTORY"? Is it folder A? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's having trouble loading your assembly rather than a dependent assembly? Have you tried running something like filemon to watch the files being accessed?

Answer (score 0):

@gTiancai: On a safer side, setting the [AssemblyName.CodeBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.codebase.aspx) property might be helpful.

This might help: [Best Practices for Assembly Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx)